# Drawing in Titlebar VB.NET 2013

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with NC painting, that even with a lot of information out there, I seem that I can't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

I plan to have a custom windowform (very much like MS OFFICE GUI). I place a small example, a string drawn in titlebar, that...doesn't get drawn.

Since the goal is to paint titlebar and borders, and other things redrawn and handled, if someone could direct me in the right way...really thanks. I would appreciate clear code examples, cause this that i bring is already from a lot of search. I already have a lot of links to examples, that I just can't get them to work.

```
    Dim hRNG1, hRNG2, hDC, hDC1, hDC2 As IntPtr
    Dim frmRECT As WinAPI.RECT
    Dim setRNG As Integer
    Dim Graphs As Graphics

    'DC for the entire screen.
    hDC = WinAPI.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)

    'BLOCK 1******************************************************************
    'Gets the clip for window/form.
    '"CreateRectRng" API function might be replaced by managed .NET class.
    hRNG1 = WinAPI.CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0)
    hDC1 = WinAPI.GetWindowDC(Me.Handle)

    setRNG = WinAPI.GetRandomRgn(hRNG1, hDC1, 4)

    'Release DC to have proper drawing (no errors or strange effects later).
    WinAPI.ReleaseDC(Me.Handle, hRNG1)

    'Value that passes from this BLOCK 1 is "hRNG1".
    '*************************************************************************
    WinAPI.GetWindowRect(Me.Handle, frmRECT)
    WinAPI.SelectClipRgn(hDC, hRNG1)
    'WinAPI.OffsetClipRgn(hDC, frmRECT.Left, frmRECT.Top)
    WinAPI.SetWindowOrgEx(hDC, -frmRECT.Left, -frmRECT.Top, IntPtr.Zero)

    Graphs = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC)
    Graphs.DrawString("I am on the title bar!", New Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 0, 4)

    Graphs.Dispose()
    WinAPI.ReleaseDC(Me.Handle, hDC)
    WinAPI.DeleteObject(hRNG)
```

I had this code in a WndProc under WM_CREATE, in a button and in FORM_PAINT. None worked. All WINAPI, STRUCTURES and CONST are in a class WinAPI

Answer (score 1):

what you are attempting is not really viable. Not saying its not doable, but from what I've learned from the WinAPI it won't get nice in the end. When I started to code really hard back in the days I did try to do what you're doing now and it was a headache.

My suggestion is that you make the form borderless and create a Custom Control to which you will add the same functionalities as the TittleBar and Borders. Its much easier and gives alot more power over the whole thing.

**And a friendly note from a fellow programmer**:

Searching and recycling code will make your program a mess. The endeavour of developing software is made up of steps. You gotta break your project into tiny little steps and accomplish them at a time, whenever you get stuck you search for ways how to do it in the internet. If the steps with which you split your project are too big you'll be looking and asking for solutions that are too specific. Chances are you're still going to be stuck, or worse you'll be recycling code from sources created with a purpose not similar to yours.

I hope I have been of help to you, the Custom Control thing really helped me alot back then and in the end I realized it was even better to harness the full customization it confers. In such a way that I ended up making every control a custom one :)

Regards!

Comment: Hi. I already have that solution prepared. But it's not working that well for MDI container form. But nevertheless, one of the points is to learn and improve my programming skills, and, being another point, having a form class that is reusable and proprietary. So, I still have interest in the API/WNDPROC solution.